# How can i print current time in kernel?

Tags: linux, time, kernel

i'm a beginner of linux. (sorry about my poor english)
I should print current time and do something through system call in linux.
I did other things but failed to print current time..
I wrote like

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/time.h>
...
asmlinkage long sys_printtime(void) {
     ...
     struct timeval time;
     struct tm tm1;
     ...

     do_gettimeofday(&time);
     local_time=(u32)(time.tv_sec -(sys_tz.tz_minuteswest * 60));
     time_to_tm(local_time,(3600*9),&tm1);
     printk(KERN_DEBUG "time @(%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d)\n", tm1.tm_year+1900,tm1.tm_mon+1,tm1.tm_mday,tm1.tm_hour,tm1.tm_min,tm1.tm_sec);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

The error said i can not use do_gettimeofday, and i finally knew that i can not use do_gettimeofday anymore because kernel5 doesn't support.
I searched on google and stackoverflow,
but i don't know how to print current time in kernel5..
anybody can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `do_gettimeofday` has been removed because of [y2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) problem. Instead the kernel provides time interfaces which you can use as per your need. Check the documentation https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html.

For example, you have `ktime_get_ts64(struct timespec64 *ts)` which will provide you time in seconds and nanoseconds.

```
struct timespec64 {
    time64_t    tv_sec;         /* seconds */
    long        tv_nsec;        /* nanoseconds */
};
```

If you only want in nanoseconds, you can use `u64 ktime_get_ns(void)`. Please check the documentation above for what suits your purpose.
Also you can check [timekeeping.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.7/source/include/linux/timekeeping.h) and [ktime.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.7/source/include/linux/ktime.h) for further information.

If you want to find an example just search the function name in the kernel source either using `grep -rni <func name>` or use `cscope`. You can also search it online [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.7/source)

Comment: Thank you so much! I already solved it using __ktime_get_real_seconds() :) I'll try again using ktime_get_ts64 as you told. thanks again x)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a one liner to get the rtc time like this:

```c
#include <linux/ktime.h>
#include <linux/rtc.h>

struct rtc_time t = rtc_ktime_to_tm(ktime_get_real());
printk(KERN_INFO "%ptRs", &t);
```

Document of `ktime_get_real` can be found [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html#c.ktime_get_real).
I didn't find any documentation for `rtc_ktime_to_tm` even in the code but it gets the time as Unix epoch in nano seconds as input and outputs `struct rtc_time`. How to print `struct rtc_time` can be found [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html#time-and-date).

Comment: Any sample output for printing struct rtc_time ?